# Is there a way to cap the maximum volume in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio

My dad just got new speakers and my sister likes to push them to maximum volume and basically destroy them.  He's asked me if there's anyway I can force the software to not let her listen to her music at such volumes.  She does not have administrative privileges, so is there a way to allow her to turn the volume up and down, but max it out at a certain volume?

Comment: Just making sure you're not trying something futile: Your speakers are not active ones which have their own hardware volume controls, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it appears that there is a program that can do this for you. It is called, quite appropriately, [Volume Lock](http://www.actualsolution.com/volume_lock/features.htm). It is trialware with a 14 day trial period. It says that it has a password function, so try it out!

Answer (score 4):

In `Control Panel > Sound > Speakers > Properties > Levels > Balance` the L and R channels can be reduced, which creates a volume cap. However, this solution relies upon this "trick" remaining undiscovered...

Comment: This doesn't address the need to lock out the volume. Security through obscurity is not wise.

Comment: @Josh K But why the downvote? I clearly pointed out this problem in the answer... (Also, it should really be possible to undo accidental comment upvotes caused by a dodgy laptop mousepad.)

Comment: No longer works in Windows 8.1